# Getting C# compilation error with nModbus4 library after switching from Net Framework to .Net 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have a code snippet, as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the code above produces a compilation error that is contradictory to the specification for the `CreateRtu` method for the `ModbsuSerialMaster` specification in the **nModbus4** library.

I'm using the **NSModbus4 (4.0.2)** package downloaded from **NuGet**.

It claims that the `CreateRtu` method requires a `TcpClient` object as the argument instead of a `SerialPort` object which worked in **Net Framework** and is what the library documentation states.

Compiled using VS2022

Comment: If you look at their source code you will see that the method you called is available only if the library is compiled with the SERIAL define. Otherwise it is cut out from the compilation and you need to use some other overloads. Have you added the source code of the library in your project and compiled it alongside your main code?

Comment: I think the reason comes from NSModbus4 doesn't contain such a definition, see my answer. :)

Comment: Hi Phillip, any update of this issue? :)

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue you encountered:

[image]

This is the source code in the **NSModbus4 (4.0.2)**:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Modbus.Data;
using Modbus.IO;
using Modbus.Message;

namespace Modbus.Device
{
    public class ModbusSerialMaster : ModbusMaster, IModbusSerialMaster, IModbusMaster, IDisposable
    {
        ModbusSerialTransport IModbusSerialMaster.Transport => (ModbusSerialTransport)base.Transport;

        private ModbusSerialMaster(ModbusTransport transport)
            : base(transport)
        {
        }

        public static ModbusSerialMaster CreateAscii(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            if (tcpClient == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("tcpClient");
            }

            return CreateAscii(new TcpClientAdapter(tcpClient));
        }

        public static ModbusSerialMaster CreateAscii(UdpClient udpClient)
        {
            if (udpClient == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("udpClient");
            }

            if (!udpClient.Client.Connected)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("UdpClient must be bound to a default remote host. Call the Connect method.");
            }

            return CreateAscii(new UdpClientAdapter(udpClient));
        }

        public static ModbusSerialMaster CreateAscii(IStreamResource streamResource)
        {
            if (streamResource == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("streamResource");
            }

            return new ModbusSerialMaster(new ModbusAsciiTransport(streamResource));
        }

        public static ModbusSerialMaster CreateRtu(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            if (tcpClient == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("tcpClient");
            }

            return CreateRtu(new TcpClientAdapter(tcpClient));
        }

        public static ModbusSerialMaster CreateRtu(UdpClient udpClient)
        {
            if (udpClient == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("udpClient");
            }

            if (!udpClient.Client.Connected)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("UdpClient must be bound to a default remote host. Call the Connect method.");
            }

            return CreateRtu(new UdpClientAdapter(udpClient));
        }

        public static ModbusSerialMaster CreateRtu(IStreamResource streamResource)
        {
            if (streamResource == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("streamResource");
            }

            return new ModbusSerialMaster(new ModbusRtuTransport(streamResource));
        }

        public bool ReturnQueryData(byte slaveAddress, ushort data)
        {
            DiagnosticsRequestResponse message = new DiagnosticsRequestResponse(0, slaveAddress, new RegisterCollection(data));
            return base.Transport.UnicastMessage<DiagnosticsRequestResponse>(message).Data[0] == data;
        }
    }
}
```

You can find that there is no definition of the method CreateRtu that contains parameter type 'SerialPort'.

nModbus4 has, but NSModbus4 doesn't.

Comment: "By the way, both of the nuget package you mentioned seems both don't support net6" - they support .NET Standard, which is sufficient to support .NET 6.